# Cannot recover from initramfs: File or directory not found when manually mounting root device

Tags: initramfs

When not specifying `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdb1` correctly in the grub shell, I get dropped to the initramfs shell. Instead of rebooting, I would like to continue boot process from there.

As explained [here](https://dev.overthere.org/wiki/How_to_recover_from_an_initramfs_shell), I want to do:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /root
exit
```

Unfortunately, the `mount` command gives me an `file or directory not found` message. This is in spite the fact that both `stat /dev/sdb` and `stat /root` give proper output.

This really leaves me puzzled. How can an existing file not be found?

The system is a Debian Stretch which I `debootstrap`'d onto an USB drive. The screen you see is what comes when booting using that USB drives.

[image: Existing files don't get found]

Answer (score 0):

If your initrd uses `dracut` then you have to create a symlink `/dev/root` to the device to be mounted (but not to do the mount). In your case:

```
ln -s /dev/sdb1 /dev/root
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `ln -s /dev/sdb1 /dev/root`? I tried it, and after typing `exit` to leave initramfs shell and continue booting, I get dropped into initramfs shell again. I added some infos regarding the OS (Debian Stretch) -- while `dracut` is in the package repository, I don't know if Debian is using `dracut` by default.

Comment: @Multisync Sorry, was a bit too tired it seems.